# WPF Games: How can I improve animation of my game map?

Tags: wpf

I am making a game in WPF.  I chose WPF because I wanted to use the layout containers and userControls in my game.  The game has two parts: 1.) The map that a character walks around on, and 2.) a UserControl composed of many containers, controls, and other userControls that acts as another screen.  I need to be able to transition from the map to the UserControl screen.

The UserControl part works great, but I am having difficulty animating the map which is an 8x5 grid of tiles of roughly 100x100 pixels.  The player is centered in the screen as the map moves:

[ScreenShot of test map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLJ1M.png)

I have tried several approaches to render the map.  I have used a timer, the CompositionTarget.Rendering event, and now I have overriden the OnRender method to draw to an Image with DrawingVisuals.  The best I can do so far is move the map 1 pixel at a time to smooth out the animation, but the motion is too slow.  In all cases, the frame rate will periodically be cut in half.  The RenderTime method gives a pattern for update times that looks something like: 16, 17, 16, 17, 16, 17, 33, 16, 17, 16, 0, 16, 17, ...(milliseconds).  I could compensate by changing how much I move the map if I knew when frames would be dropped ahead of time.

Is there a way to do this or is there another method that might get the job done?  I am open to using any approach that allows 1.) and 2.) to happen, but the userControl must be a WPF Control(as I have spent a lot of time on that part.)  Thanks!

*UPDATED*
: The following WPF project is my latest attempt at getting smooth rending of the 8x5 map that I mentioned.

The MainWindow.xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RenderingBitmapTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowState="Minimized">
    <Grid>
        <Image Name="Background"/>
        <Button Name="MoveDownButton" Height="35" Width="100" Content="Press Me!" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="Blue" Height="50" Width="50"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the MainWindow.xaml.vb file:

```
Imports System.Security.Permissions
Imports System.Windows.Threading

Class MainWindow
    Private buffer As RenderTargetBitmap
    Private drawingVisual As New DrawingVisual

    ' FPS counter '
    Dim tSec As Integer = TimeOfDay.Second
    Dim tTicks As Integer = 0
    Dim MaxTicks As Integer = 0

    ' Motion Testing '
    Dim moveX As Double = 0
    Dim moveY As Double = 0

    Dim IsRunning As Boolean = True

    Dim grass As New BitmapImage(New Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/GrassTile2.png")) 'Image is 100 x 100 '
    Dim tree As New BitmapImage(New Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Tree2.png"))

    Protected Overrides Sub OnRender(ByVal drawingContext As DrawingContext)
        MyBase.OnRender(drawingContext)
        buffer = New RenderTargetBitmap(CInt(Me.ActualWidth), CInt(Me.ActualHeight), 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32)
        Background.Source = buffer
    End Sub

    Private Sub Drawing()
        If buffer Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If

        buffer.Clear()

        Using dc As DrawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen()

            For X = 0 To 7
                For Y = 0 To 4
                    dc.DrawImage(grass, New Rect(moveX + Me.Width / 7 * X, moveY + Me.Height / 5 * Y, Me.Width / 6.9, Me.Height / 4.9))
                    dc.DrawText(New FormattedText(MaxTicks, Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"), FlowDirection.LeftToRight, New Typeface("Verdana"), 32, Brushes.Black), New Point(0, 0))
                Next
            Next
            'Trees added. '
            dc.DrawImage(tree, New Rect(moveX + 700, moveY + 400, Me.Width / 8, Me.Height / 3))
            dc.DrawImage(tree, New Rect(moveX + 1000, moveY + 300, Me.Width / 8, Me.Height / 3))
        End Using

        buffer.Render(drawingVisual)
    End Sub

    Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        Me.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized

    End Sub

    Private Sub Background_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Background.Loaded
        While IsRunning
            TickCounter()

            If Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Up) Then
                moveY += 5 '1'
            ElseIf Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Down) Then
                moveY -= 5 '1'
            ElseIf Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Left) Then
                moveX += 5 '1'
            ElseIf Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Right) Then
                moveX -= 5 '1'
            End If

            DoEvents()
            Drawing()

        End While

    End Sub

    Private Sub TickCounter()
        If tSec = TimeOfDay.Second And IsRunning = True Then
            tTicks = tTicks + 1
        Else
            MaxTicks = tTicks
            tTicks = 0
            tSec = TimeOfDay.Second
        End If

    End Sub

    '<Do Events>'
    <SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags:=SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)>
    Public Sub DoEvents()
        Dim frame As New DispatcherFrame()
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, New DispatcherOperationCallback(AddressOf ExitFrame), frame)
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame)
    End Sub

    Public Function ExitFrame(ByVal f As Object) As Object
        CType(f, DispatcherFrame).Continue = False

        Return Nothing
    End Function
    '</Do Events>'

    Private Sub MainWindow_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed
        IsRunning = False
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub MoveDownButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles MoveDownButton.Click
        moveY -= 5
    End Sub

End Class
```

If anyone can get a working smooth animated game map on keypress with another method, please let me know.  I am currently working on a 4 year old toshiba laptop, but I have ran this code on newer computers and the same problems are present.  I would like this game to run on any computer capable of running WPF applications.

Comment: WPF provides animation already (e.g through storyboards). Use that. Let the library worry about framerates. You can hook into that system by using a combination of storyboards with binding to properties in your view model.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Matt.  I have worked with storyboards in the different parts of the game for short or periodic animations.  I assumed that any storyboard animations would be prone to the problems of the CompositionTarget.Rendering event.  I will try to update the map position with storyboard animations triggered by a keydown event handler in another test project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just spitballing here as there's a plethora of potential issues and trying to solve a problem sight-unseen is guess work at best of the time, but having said that I have a few areas that you may want to dig into for further thought:

> 1. If framerates are not consistent, can you identify specific points in time when this inconsistency occurs? I.e. When a large number of animations are running at once, or when a specific brush is used?
>
>    > - Have you used any profiling tools in order to find 'hot' parts of your code? This may help in identifying specific scenarios where these inconsistencies occur.
> 2. What is the DesiredFrameRate of the animation in question, and other animations which may be running at the same time? By default this is 60fps, and this can get quite taxing, particularly when where are a lot of objects on screen or transitions being polled.
>
>    > - First Try setting `Timeline.DesiredFrameRate=60` on your hitching animation.
>    > - Secondly try setting the `DesiredFrameRate` of other Timelines to say 30 in order to observe if this increases performance for your map- this would elude to the quantity or quality of other elements causing the performance impact.
> 3. Have you looked into the RenderQuality of the brushes you're using for the map and your visual objects?
>
>    - Try reducing the RenderQuality of your brushes: `RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(myBrush, BitmapScalingMode.LowQuality);`
>    - Ensure your re-usable brushes are being cached: `RenderOptions.SetCachingHint(myBrush, CachingHint.Cache);`

There are a lot of potential performance bottlenecks and without seeing code its difficult to provide you with more than these loose suggestions. As a quick first-stop for baseline optimisations, there is a fairly [comprehensive post by Kevin Pfister](http://mrpfister.com/journal/improving-wpf-rendering-performance/) which may provide some further useful insight in lieu of any code or specific identified problem areas.

If there were more information provided, such as:

- What your hardware setup consists of, and if this issue persists on other (more powerful) machines.
- If you're deferring rendering to GPU, and indeed what the GPU is.
- What architecture(s) and platforms you are targetting. I.e. is this a Xamarin project, Win32WPF or something else?
- Wheter or not you are experiencing this only with debug symbols enabled.

I might have been able to give you some more suggestions.

Comment: I have added the MainWindow files for a test project where the OnRender method is overriden.  I cannot use the timeline property yet because I am not using a storyboard to do animation.  I will try this next as suggested by Matt Burland.

Comment: Ah gotcha, I'm sadly not able to offer any additional help then in that case as I've no experience in not using the provided library for animation within WPF.

Comment: That's ok JC.  It turned out that using storyboards resulted in the same problems.  I am currently looking into using an OpenTK control for WPF to render the game graphics.  In my case, the airspace issue can be avoided because the WPF user control is separate from the game map part of the game.  Though there is another library for C# called SharpGL that apparently has a control for WPF that somehow avoids the airspace problem.  I will post an update to let everyone know how it turned out.  Thanks.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the update t0mr. Interested to see what the results are!